# Retrieve data from URL in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I'm trying to make a referrals application. The only problem is that when I access the link that leads me to the register page, I have a parameter in the URL, I don't know, I don't realize how I can take that parameter from the URL and assign it to the created user. I tried to do a function but I don't realize, again, how I can get the data from that function variable in created user.

The column that generates referral links:

```
        <td>{{ route('refs.user',['name' => $referralCategory->name,'id'=>$referralCategory->id]) }}</td>
```

web.php

```
Route::get('refs/{name}/{id}','ReferralCategoryController@refs')->name('refs.user');
```

And the function that redirects to the register page

```
public function refs($name = null,$id = null){
        //dd($name);
        if(!$id){
            return redirect(route('login'));
        }
        else{

            if($id){
                $refCategory = ReferralCategory::where('id', $id)->first();
                ReferralCategory::where('id', $id)->update([
                    'referral_visits' => $refCategory->referral_visits + 1
                ]);
            }
            return redirect()->route('register', ['name' => $name]);

        }
        if(Cookie::get('id')){
            return(route('register'));
        }
        return response(route('register'))
        ->cookie('id', $id, 60*24*30*12)
        ->cookie('name',$name, 60*24*30*12);
    }
```

The register controller:

> ```
> Route::get('register/{name}','Auth\RegisterController@register_ref')->name('register_ref.cat');
> ```

```
<?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

    use App\User;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    class RegisterController extends Controller
    {
        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Register Controller
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |
        | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
        | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
        | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
        |
        */

        use RegistersUsers;

        /**
         * Where to redirect users after registration.
         *
         * @var string
         */
        protected $redirectTo = '/home';

        /**
         * Create a new controller instance.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->middleware('guest');
        }

        /**
         * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
         *
         * @param  array  $data
         * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
         */
        protected function validator(array $data)
        {
            return Validator::make($data, [
                'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
                'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
                'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
                'referred_by' => 'string|max:20',
            ]);
        }

        public function register_ref( $name = null){


            return redirect()->route('register', ['name' => $name]);


        }

        /**
         * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
         *


   * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {       


            return User::create(    [

                'name' => $data['name'],
                'email' => $data['email'],
                'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
                'referred_by' => $data['referred_by'],

                ]);


    }


}
```

Comment: Hi! Do you want to get the name and put into register form view?

Comment: No, i just want to take the name and insert into table, without putting the column in the form

Comment: look through this `return redirect()->route('register', ['name' => $name]);` your are sending name into your register view so you have to put input type hidden in your register view and echo $name in hidden type value when you'll submit form then you can receive it. make any sense or not?Let me know . Thanks

Comment: I think I know, you mean that name from URL i have to receive into an input/label field and put on hiding and then I will have to take that input in the create?

Comment: In the register.blade i do something like this: {{ app('request')->input('name') }}

Comment: I think like that `<input name="name" type="hidden" value="{{$name }}"/>`

Comment: it works like this  <input type="text" class="form-control" id = "referred_by" name="referred_by" value="{{ Request::get('name') }}" placeholder="Referral email">
           but, when i put the name 'referred_by' in create it inserted me as null,. (i data in the input)

Comment: i updated the post with the new register controller\

Comment: In User model `referred_by` it must be in protected `$fillable array`

Comment: yes, i put the column there\

Comment: kindly `dd($data)` in create method to check whether you are getting created_by value or not

Comment: it looks like this : 

^ array:6 [▼
  "_token" => "iucEjD8HTn7PvoOm2I0ndjqEL2vfCVcDE0ZZm26w"
  "name" => "sadads"
  "email" => "vvvvb@gmail.com"
  "password" => "vvvvb@gmail.com"
  "referred_by" => "FaceBook"
  "password_confirmation" => "vvvvb@gmail.com"
]

Comment: So, my reffered_by have values but..

Comment: so exactly you have invalid `data type in` your table for field `referred_by` check and make sure `varchar` and has length `155`

Comment: in my table i have reffered_by varchar(191)..

Comment: Can you update your question and list your User model code too. Thanks

Comment: Thank you so much for your time sir, i solved, i go to the repositories and i had to put it into fillable, i just did only for the user in models.

Comment: HI you posted `reffered_by varchar(191).` check spelling too are you declaring correct variable

Comment: I told you before you must put in fallible. Thanks at least thumb up for me. Thanks

Comment: yes, i know you said that but i just put on the Models folder and for the Repositories i forgot :D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables, you pass through the route, can be called directly in the method:

```
public function helloWorld($variableFromRoute) { }
```

**Better**: If you want to register a user, you should work with http post request.

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('route_name') }}">
  <input type="text" name="username">
  <input type="password" name="pw">
  <input type="password" name="pw_repeated">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register">
</form>

public function register(Request $request) {
  // validate
  // create record
  // redirect
}
```

**Best**: ...Or just use the laravel auth system.

Comment: I want to register a user, but i want that user to be from a referral link sent from via email. I write a function as you write but when i want to put in the create it's null.

Comment: Please post your code. Sometimes users forget to execute the save()-method after they filled the class attributes of the model. (https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#insert-update-delete)

Answer (score -1):

Just use pure PHP

```
$ref = $_GET['ref'];
```